# Does the following sequence converge in the metric space $(X,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

If we have the set $X=(0,\infty)$ and metric $d(x,y)=\left |\ln \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \right |$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Does $\{x_n\}=1/n$ converge in $(X,d)$.

My thoughts:

Let us suppose that the limit exists and call it $l$. Then we can make $d(1/n,l)=|\ln(1/nl)|< \epsilon$ for $\epsilon >0$ provided we take $n$ sufficiently large. Clearly this is rubbish since $1/nl \rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ so $\ln (1/nl) \rightarrow -\infty$.

So it cannot converge.

Could anyone help me formalise this some more or is it okay?

Comment: It's ok: the condition $d(1/n, l) \to 0$ cannot be satisfied by any $l\in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine to me.  An alternate way to write it would be to recognise that $\left|\ln \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right| = |\ln x - \ln y|$.  Then:
\begin{eqnarray} d\left(\frac{1}{n},l\right) & = & \left|\ \ln \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \ln l \ \right| \\
& = & \left| -\ln n -\ln l \right| \\
& = & \left| (-1)(\ln n + \ln l)\right| \\
& = & |\ln n + \ln l|
\end{eqnarray}

Thus $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty} d(1/n, l) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\ln n + \ln l| \rightarrow \infty$ for any fixed limit value $l \in X$

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility consists in noticing that $\log\colon X\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism (and, in fact an isometry). Therefore, if the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ was convergent, than the sequence $\left(\log\left(\frac1n\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would be convergent in $\mathbb R$ with respect to the usual topology. But, since it is an unbounded sequence, that does not happen.